# Can not obtain connection to DB using JPA - derby embedded driver class missing

Tags: java, maven, jpa, database-connection, derby

I am trying to create local derby database using jpa. As JPA implementation i am using openjpa and as sql implementation derby.

This is persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="DataLayer"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <non-jta-data-source>DataSource</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="create" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:derby:testdb" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Persistence.generateSchema("DataLayer", null);
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DataLayer");
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager(); // <- Exception here
}
```

This is starting part of exception i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-3.1.2-r66d2a72 nonfatal general error> org.a
pache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There were errors initializing y
our configuration: <openjpa-3.1.2-r66d2a72 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.
util.UserException: A connection could not be obtained for driver class "org.apa
che.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" and URL "jdbc:derby:testdb".  You may have spe
cified an invalid URL.
...
```

saying that i may have specified an invalid URL.

Complete stack trace: https://justpaste.it/3kmgo

**Root exception**: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

I have specified EmbeddedDriver in persistence.xml, also included Maven dependency.

Also i think my connection url and driver is correct according to docs about derby:

- https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/devguide/rdevdvlp22102.html#rdevdvlp22102
- https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/devguide/cdevdvlp40653.html

Dependencies included (using Maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.15.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to change property `javax.persistence.jdbc.url` to `jdbc:derby:testdb;create=true`, but same exception. Also tried to set `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action` property to `none`.

Comment: Note that you're using Derby 10.15 but your question indicates you're reading the docs from Derby version 10.4 and 10.8, which are quite old. In the error message that you posted, it says "EmbeddeasddDriver" -- what is that value and how did it get there? Is that a clue?

Comment: @BryanPendleton Oh my... sorry, i edited question. I wrote that "asd" there probably by mistake. And i checked those docs 10.15, replaced them in question, but that connectivity stuff remains same.

Comment: Good, makes sense. Try to get the *complete* task trace of your exception. I'm not very familiar with what Maven does, but I suspect that you don't have the correct jars in your CLASSPATH. In particular, you are probably missing derbyshared.jar. Read the DERBY-6945 release note here: https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.15.1.3.html

Comment: @BryanPendleton I haved included full stack trace of my exception to the question. Root exception is that EmbeddedDriver class is missing, as u suspected that i do not have correct jars in my classapth. Changed question name. However, i have specified that class in persistence.xml and included Maven dependency :/

Comment: I think your "artifactid" is wrong. I think that 'derbyclient' is for the Client-Server networked configuration of Derby. Since you are using the Embedded configuration of derby, try specifying 'derby' as the artifactid instead.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Tried that sir. Same exception. Also tried deleting all module-info.java from projects, which also did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` class is not in `derby` *artifactid* dependency (it has derby and derbyshared jar's). It is in *derbytools*, so including *derbytools* to dependencies solve issue abbout missing `EmbeddedDriver` class:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbytools</artifactId>
    <version>10.15.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score -1):

Using Debry 10.15.2.0 the Embedded driver is located in Derbytools.jar.  Thus must be in your libraries and classpath.  Created a new driver(I'd deleted any drivers that say anything Embedded). In the Services tab right click Drivers and Create New.  Add Derbytools.jar Highlight it and click the Find Button.  Give it a meaningful name and it works as expected.  Just to be sure I also added Derby.jar and DerbyShared.jar to avoid problems.

Comment: The OP is using maven to manage the dependencies; you seem to be describing how to add dependencies in some IDE, which is not relevant for the question. The gist of your solution (adding derbytools) is correct, though - but Wortig already figured that out.